# Using Underwater Robot Model on ROS (Noetic) and Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

I have to work with ROS Noetic and gazebo on a model of a Semi-submerged drone. To test some different programs, I want to use the model of diffboat, located in [this git](https://github.com/disaster-robotics-proalertas/usv_sim_lsa).
Because Kinetic might close in few days, i have to work with ROS Noetic (or Foxy/ROS2) and the problem is this project is not compatible with ROS Noetic..
Do you have any advice to make this project compatible on ROS/Noetic?

Comment: There is a branch in the project where the developer was porting to ros melodic. Not sure the status of that but it might work for you

Answer (score 1):

Hi am not sure if you have to work with the mentioned environment or if also unity instead of gazebo is an alternative.
But if you want to check out other maritime simulators I can recommend these links to you:

[Ros Discourse on Maritime Robotics](https://discourse.ros.org/c/maritime/36)

[UUV Simulator](https://uuvsimulator.github.io/) (Ros,Gazebo)

[DAVE Simulator](https://github.com/Field-Robotics-Lab/dave/wiki) (Ros,Gazebo)

[Plankton Simulator](https://github.com/Liquid-ai/Plankton) (Ros2,Gazebo)